# Check this topology exercise.

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying *Topology (2nd ed.)*, by James Munkres, and I'd like to check if this is right:

> Show that the countable collection
>   $$\left\lbrace(a,b)\times(c,d)\;|\;a<b,\;c<d\;\;\text{ and }\;\;a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}\right\rbrace$$
>   is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$

I skip proving that's a basis because I have no problems with that, for the rest,
I prove it by double inclusion:

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology generated by that basis. If $U$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$, then for every $x\in U$, there is a basis element $(a,b)\times (c,d)$ that also contains $x$, but that will also hold because we know tha open rectangles produce the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $\mathcal{T}\subset \mathbb{R^2}$.

Now for the oposite, if $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and all the four numbers are rational, then it belongs to the previous basis and it is also open in $\mathcal{T}$. If any of those is irrational, we can still form it as unions of basis elements this way:

$$(a,b)\times(c,d)=\bigcup (x_1,x_2)\times(x_3,x_4)$$

With $x_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ and the next conditions:

$$a<x_3<c \\b<x_4<d\\ a<x_1<x_3\\b<x_2<x_4$$

That is just going through the rectangle with rational numbers.

---

Ok, while I was writing I realised that taking opens in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ was not enough because not all opens look like that.

The other solution I can think of is starting from the known fact of open rectangles being a basis for the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so the collection belongs to a basis, plus the resting elements can still be formed by unions of sets of the collection the same way I did above, and so they must form the same topology. Am I right here?

EDIT: I think I just realised my two solutions are actually the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to show that $\mathcal{T}$ includes all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it's enough to show that it contains some basis of the standard topology e. g. the rectangles.